# Can I use "parallel myriad" in a sentence and would that be an oxymoron?

Tags: oxymoron

The sentance is:

**Task**: Add two APIs to the ESB.

**Info**: *Parallel Myriad* task which involves all seven systems to work together and deliver this.

Comment: The two words used together make no sense to me. How can a myriad (an extremely large number) be parallel to something?

Comment: I'm with @KateBunting in having no idea what you are trying to communicate. Also, why would you think that "parallel myriad" is an oxymoron?

Comment: What do you think "myriad" means here? It doesn't seem to have the usual meaning in English of a large number. A "parallel task" is a well-defined concept (something you can do in parallel with other tasks), but a "myriad task" is not.

Comment: Thanks @KateBunting that is clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

If your myriad tasks are in two different universes, environments or states then yes, why not?

Can not a colony of ants perform a myriad of tasks in their anthill whilst a colony of bees perform a myriad of tasks in their hive next door?

But if you are speaking of only one environment - then no, I would say it is tautology.  And also - myriad implies more a miasma whereas parallel implies 2 things in lines.

If by saying ‘parallel’ you are wanting to convey the idea that everything is going on at the same time, then I would use ‘simultaneous myriad’ rather than ‘parallel’. Or, ‘universal myriad’ to mean ‘it’s all going on at once!’

I surmise that you are referring to a myriad *of tasks* in your question.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/myriad